# SQL Server : Insert second result table of a stored procedure into dynamic temp table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, resultset, temp-tables

For everyone understanding, I am explaining my requirement simply

I have a stored procedure called 'REC_VENDOR_SELECT'. It returns two tables as result.

Now, I want to insert the second table rows (returned by stored procedure) into a dynamic temp table.

I could see some solutions but those are for inserting the first table into temp table. But I want to insert the second or nth table of the stored procedure result.

Comment: You should add the schema, definition and the sample data of related tables, procedures for the better understanding of your query.

Comment: While it's possible to return multiple result sets from a stored procedure as you're doing it does make things more difficult. You're not going to be able to do this with a pure SQL solution. Even the tSQLt Test Framework's ResultSetFilter is a .NET CLR procedure so that it can capture the separate result sets from queries and procs under test, which it does by way of a DataReader.

Comment: *Now, I want to insert the second table rows (returned by stored procedure) into a dynamic temp table.* Is this an all the time thing, or occasional? If it's all the time, why not do it in the `REC_VENDOR_SELECT` procedure? Optionally, you could pass a flag into the SP that could instruct the SP to create the temp table rather than return its results, otherwise there's no native way to do this in SQL Server T-SQL.